# One Function in Python to Iterate Over Concurrent Lists to be Used in Equation

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have four separate lists of integers that I need to use concurrently in an equation:

```
h = [160, 193, 162, 17, 0]
d = [32, 1, 34, 35, 4]
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
r = [2, 5, 1, 3, 4]

s = h - (d + t + r)
```

I am trying to create one function to which I can pass each separate list as an argument to use in the function.  I want to be able to take the value at each successive index on each list and then use them in the correct place in the equation.  I would then take the value of s at each index and populate a new list.

So for example the equation at index[0] should read:

```
s = 160 - (32 + 1 + 2)
```

How can I take each integer value from  list?  I have tried to use the enumerate function and I have read about the * function, but I am not sure that I am supposed to be unpacking the lists - should I not just be iterating over them with a for loop?

```
def getSingles(h, d, r, t)
    singles = []
    for n, val in enumerate(h):
        hit = val
    for n, val in enumerate(d):
        double = val
    for n, val in enumerate(t):
        triple = val
    for n, val in enumerate(r):
        run = val
```

I am basically suck here - is this even possible?  Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: @simonzack are you just here to troll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` function and a lambda in `map` :

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[0] - (x[1] + x[2] + x[3]),zip(h,d,t,r))
[125, 185, 124, -25, -13]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them together. Something like this should work:

```
>>> H = [160, 193, 162, 17, 0]
>>> D = [32, 1, 34, 35, 4]
>>> T = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> R = [2, 5, 1, 3, 4]
>>> 
>>> for h, d, t, r in zip(H, D, T, R):
...     s = h - (d + t + r)
...     print(s)
... 
125
185
124
-25
-13
```

Note that if you're using Python 2.x and using very large lists, you might want to use [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead.

Comment: It's 2014, python 3's been released for long enough.

Comment: @simonzack except the majority of the world is still using 2.x

Comment: But FWIW, I updated the answer for both 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: I suppose that's why you're directing new programmers to python 2.

Comment: I'm not directing them. I'm assuming they're using 2.x, which is usually the case.

Comment: @jterrace Thank You!! This can be done at either the global or local level?

Comment: @flamingjune5dwj yes - you could pass the lists to the function if you want

Comment: I am actually using python 3.x but I am glad to know that it will work for either.

Answer (score 1):

A [pandas Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#series) makes this easy:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> h = pd.Series([160, 193, 162, 17, 0])
>>> d = pd.Series([32, 1, 34, 35, 4])
>>> t = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> r = pd.Series([2, 5, 1, 3, 4])
>>> s = h - (d + t + r)
>>> s
0    125
1    185
2    124
3    -25
4    -13
dtype: int64
```

If you have h,d,t,r data in a CSV file, you can use `pandas.read_csv()` to read that into a pandas Dataframe.  A Dataframe is like an array of Series, and can calculate new columns in a similar fashion.